# Facebook like button's "comments popup window" is half displayed

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm using Twenty Eleven theme of WordPress.

In other themes, there is no problem but in twenty eleven there is a problem with Facebook like button's comments popup window. it's half shown. when I click "Like" button, the view is like below:

[image]

You can see the website at: http://www.deneyimokulu.com/

I use Facebook plugin for Wordpress. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This question doesnt really belong here. The Fix is in your theme CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a span element right before the iframe of the like buttons.

`<span style="height: 20px; width: 85px;">`

Try change this to:

`<span style="height: 20px; width: 450px;">`

or add the width to the below element:

.fb_iframe_widget span {display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align: justify; vertical-align: text-bottom; **width: 450px !important;** }